# How can I get my regular express to capture complete sentences and not abbreviations

Tags: regex

I have some long text strings that are a series of concatenated sentences.  I have written a regular expression that captures individual complete sentences by combining a period match and a positive lookahead.  Where I'm running into trouble is when my text includes common abbreviations like (Mr. Dr. Mrs.) My regular express is treating these abbreviations like complete sentences and therefore yielding bad results.

Does anyone have an idea around this situation.

The regular expression I'm using is this:

```
/(\S.+?[.?!])(?=\s+|$)/gm
```

and my sample text is this:

```
Bill attended the meeting and provide some valuable input.  John was at the meeting but said nothing. Mr. Smith could not attend.  A. B. Butler presented the financial results and took questions.
```

Ideally I would get four captures - one for each sentence, but I'm getting six because Mr. and A. B. are being treated as sentences.

You can see the results of my regular expression here:

[regex101 - Sample Regular Expression](https://regex101.com/r/wE8kU4/1)

I'm using javascript.

Comment: If you can depend on there being two spaces after the sentence end period (deprecated), then you can search for that: (\S.+?[.\s?!])(?=\s\s|$)/gm - But that doesn't seem like a dependable assumption in the real world

Comment: @jrq unfortunately, the data is not that uniformed.  Though in most cases I find there is only one space between sentences.

Comment: try this https://regex101.com/r/wE8kU4/2

Comment: @AvinashRaj that seems to work like a charm.  If you care to write up a formal answer I will gladly give you the check mark.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below regex would work for your case.

```
(\S.*? [a-z]+[.?!])(?=\s+|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wE8kU4/2)

Comment: What if the sentence ends with a capitalized word (e.g., "He gave the book to John.")?